# why does atomic operator $ work with character, but not character stored in variable?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called "groups", with column names "A" through "H".

Any idea what's the problem with this and how to fix it?

```
for(i in colnames(groups)){

   print(groups$i)

}


> NULL
> NULL
> NULL
> NULL
> NULL
> NULL
> NULL
> NULL
```

Especifically, why is this so?

```
groups$"A"


> "Ecuador"
> "Netherlands"
> "Qatar"
> "Senegal"



i <- "A"

groups$i


> NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

**Return data frame**

```
for(i in 1:length(groups)){
  print(groups[i])
  }
```

**Return a vector**

```
for(i in 1:length(groups)){
  print(groups[[i]])
  }
```

edit: I added @user2554330's fix.

Comment: yeah, eventually i figured it out, ha! i was tunnel-visioned trying to use $. thank you very much anyways!

Comment: That should actually be `groups[[i]]` to match `groups$A`: it returns the column instead of a new dataframe containing one column.

Comment: so double brackets should work? interesting!